# Angular with CoffeeScript and Jade for front-end, Node, Express and CoffeeScript for back-end

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, coffeescript

I'm about to begin developing Web apps outside of MS environment.
Been doing some searching across different technology stacks, to see what appeals the most.

After about a week of searching, exploring, looking at a whole bunch of PluralSite videos, I start to really like the idea of the following combo:

- Using Node.js in combination with Express framework  to develop the back-end using CoffeeScript as the main language
- Using AngularJS in combination with Jade templates to develop the front-end SPA using CeffeeScript as the main language as well.

My question is: are both of my choices completely valid together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no technical reason these frameworks can't work together, and no special synergy that would make them strictly better than other combinations.

In other words, it's a matter of opinion. Give it a try, and see if you like the feel.